# How to toggle component based on click index in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

```
var Comp = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function(){
        return {hide: false};
    },
    toggle: function(){
        this.setState({hide: !this.state.hide});
    },
    render: function() {
        return <div>
            <button onClick={this.toggle}>toggle</button>    
            <div className={'hide-' + this.state.hide}>Hi there</div>

      <button onClick={this.toggle}>toggle</button>    
            <div className={'hide-' + this.state.hide}>Hi there</div>

      <button onClick={this.toggle}>toggle</button>    
            <div className={'hide-' + this.state.hide}>Hi there</div>

      <button onClick={this.toggle}>toggle</button>    
            <div className={'hide-' + this.state.hide}>Hi there</div>
        </div>;
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(
    <Comp />,
    document.getElementById('container')
);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9lessons/aLd1w6qs/3/

Comment: ...is there a question here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using a **common state variable** to toggle the `div`. Since it is shared among all `div`s changing visibility of one would change all of them simultaneously.

You can create either separete state variable for each of div e.g hide1, hide2 .....hideN.

Or

Try another approach- creating separate component itself.

```
var ToggleableComp = React.createClass({
    getInitialState:function() {
        return {hide: false};
    },
    toggle: function(){
        this.setState({hide: !this.state.hide});
    },
    render: function() {
      return (
        <div>
        <button onClick={this.toggle}>toggle</button>    
            <div className={'hide-' + this.state.hide}>{this.props.children}</div>
        </div>
      );
    }
});

var Comp = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
           <div>
             <ToggleableComp>Json Data 1</ToggleableComp>
             <ToggleableComp>Json Data 2</ToggleableComp>
             <ToggleableComp>Json Data 3</ToggleableComp>
             <ToggleableComp>Json Data 5</ToggleableComp>
        </div>
      );
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(
    <Comp />,
    document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a4tp2uut/)

Comment: thank you, but my components are loading based on JSON render.

Comment: <button onClick={this.toggle}>toggle</button>   <div className={'hide-' + this.state.hide}>{data.content}</div>

Comment: In that case you can pass data as props to ToggleableComp or as children.

Comment: I have tried this http://jsfiddle.net/9lessons/t37Lk6p4/169/ , could you please help me

Comment: Please update the question in full detail what you want to achieve ? It will be easy to help.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for this question, try to click comment button.

```
var EachCom = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function(){
    return { showComment: false };
    },
    commentLink: function()
    {
    this.setState({ showComment: !this.state.showComment });
    this.renderCommentForm;
    },
    renderCommentForm: function()
    {

if(this.state.showComment)
{
return (<CommentForm />)
}

},
render: function(){
return <div><br/>
<button onClick={this.commentLink}> comment </button>
{this.renderCommentForm()}
 </div>
}
});

var TaskList = React.createClass({


    render: function(){
        return <div>
            {this.props.items.map((task, taskIndex) => 
                <div key={taskIndex}>
                    {task}
                    <EachCom />

                </div>
            )}
        </div>;
    }
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9lessons/t37Lk6p4/171/